# How can I draw image by pdfsharp without translation?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I'm trying to draw a image to pdf  page with rotate transform. The problem is when I draw it without any transform the coordinate is right so the image is putted correctly(here is x = 0 and y = 0). But when I try to rotate(90Deg) the image before drawing, event if I set new coordinate, the image is not putted at the point that I want to.

Here's I tried:

```
 gp.TranslateTransform(modelWidth / 2, modelHeight / 2);

            if (angle > 0)
            {
                gp.RotateTransform(angle);
            }

            gp.TranslateTransform(-modelWidth / 2, -modelHeight / 2);

            /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            gp.DrawImage(xImg, new Drawing.Point(0, 0));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't rotate the Image, you rotate the graphics context.

The co-ordinates passed to DrawImage must reflect the transformations.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_an_image_transformed_22